# Привязка рисунка в MS Word

Tags: форматирование, ms-word

Если в MS Word у рисунка задана привязка "в тексте", то все настройки его положения выключены. Возникла  необходимость сместить такие рисунки по высоте, т.е. изменить вертикальное выравнивание по нижнему краю на выравнивание по центру. Можно ли как-нибудь это сделать?

Comment: Руками. Ну этот вопрос не относится к программированию, он относится к тому что кто-то не в ладах с ПО MS Office. Только и всего.

Comment: Все-таки, как? В каком файле какой параметр изменить? Совершенно согласен, что вопрос не по программированию - это вопрос по настройке ПО. В штатном режиме эксплуатации эта настройка не регулируется, нужны какие-то нештатные "ручные" действия. У кого же это еще узнавать, кроме как у программистов?

Comment: Ну да, кнопочка "Положение", далее привязка "В тексте" - и все, все настройки серые. Другие привязки "По контуру", "Вокруг рамки" и т.д. в данном случае не нужны - требуется привязка изображения к конкретному символу строки.

Comment: Привязка изображения к конкретному символу строки? Круто взяли )) Думаю, что даже время не стоит тратить на поиски такой встроенной функции.

Comment: Когда мы вставляем рисунок с привязкой "в тексте" именно так и происходит. Правда, скорей всего нужно говорить о привязке не к символу, а к слову, но это сути не меняет, слово может быть и из одного символа. Главное, что при форматировании такая последовательность "слово1"-"рисунок"-"слово2" сохраняется. И никакая дополнительная встроенная функция здесь не нужна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приветствую.
Решение для Word 2003. Чтобы выравнить, а в предложенном способе точнее будет "подогнать", привязанное к тексту изображение по высоте, выберите рисунок; выберите в меню Формат > Шрифт...; далее на вкладке Интервал выберите Смещение > Вниз > Например, на 4 пт.
Успехов!

Comment: Большое спасибо! Действительно, выход, сейчас запишу макрос.

Answer (score 0):

> У кого же это еще узнавать, кроме как у программистов?

Я вот, к прмеру, MS Word знаю на процентов 50, но это мне не мешает программировать. Зато мне хватило одной минуты, чтоб найти кнопочку "Положение" и выбрать оцентровку по вертикали

[image]

Comment: Это 2007 или 2010? Просто у меня 2003, там этого нет.

Comment: MS Office 2007

Comment: Спасибо, поставлю 2007.